# Finding correct CSS sheet when Chrome Inspector shows (index)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

In a wordpress site, I'm trying to remove a pesky bottom border that is clashing with a widget I have in the footer of each page. When using Chrome inspector, it shows the source as being from (index):1480 for each individual page it is on. That leads me to believe that wordpress is dynamically embedding this into the html of every page that I create, but I can't figure out how to fix that.

I can remove it with the Inspector by changing the border from 1px to 0px but I don't know the proper way to fix it.  I've walked through about every CSS sheet I can find, searching for #505152 which is the color of the line and I can't find it.

How do I locate it?

The site is www.pitchnotecreative.com, and I'm referring to the Recent Blog Posts at the bottom - you can see a thin grey line just under Animate this and for the Films and TV, you can see there are actually two lines that run through it since it is multiple lines.  HELP!

Comment: I look this style attached in your <head> tag. You may find something interesting in `head.php` or `header.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use specifity to make sure your stylesheet value is the one used, i.e. identify the element more closely...this should work

```
 .footer-area ul li .rpwe-title a {border-bottom: 0px!important);
```

Comment: I tried styling .rpwe-title a previously and it didn't work but adding the footer part did the trick.  Thank you!